# Node.js ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js

I tried the code below on BOTH Windows 7 and Mac Snow Leopard and I received the same error with Node.js 0.12.0

I have other port numbers, I have tried using 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1'.  I have the IP in my host file under C:\Windows\System32.  I am at a loss here but the behavior is consistent and I am seeing lots of chatter on the web with no REAL answers or solutions but people here get solid answers.

Response from Node.js command prompt

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Code

```
var http = require('http');

var makeRequest = function(message) {
  var options = {
      host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8080, path: '/', method: 'POST', headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/text',
      'Content-Length': message.length
    }
  }

  var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });

  process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  request.write(message);
  request.end();    
}

makeRequest('Hi!!!!');
```

Comment: You're not seeing REAL answers b/c there are too many possibilities! The most likely cause of the problem is that there is no service on port 8080 of localhost. Can you verify outside node that the host/port/method is working as expected (say with Chrome's Postman or `curl -X POST ...`)?

Comment: I can use the command telnet 127.0.0.1 8080 and I get .... Could not open a connection to the host, on port 8080: Connection failed.  I presume I will need to open port 8080.  Not sure how to do that

Comment: Hard to know what you're trying to do here - sounds like maybe you're trying to test a basic http client request in node. If thats the case...just make a fake server over at http://requestb.in and update the host/port info in your code above. If you want to make both clients and servers, find yourself a tutorial on node servers (say, http://www.nodebeginner.org/#a-basic-http-server).

Comment: The request bin suggest is something new, I will try that.  I did create a virtual machine in IIS exposing the port 8080 and I now am able to connect using the command: telnet 127.0.0.1 8080 but when I run command: node make_request I get data back in the buffer but I don't get the response 'Hi' from fiddler.  Instead I get a 403 error.  That directory only has JavaScript files in it btw....